# "Cannot create asynchronous query while in a write transaction" exception

Tags: macos, swift3, realm

After migrating mine OS X application from swift 2.2 to swift 3.0 (realm version has also changed from 1.0.2 to 2.1.1) some of write transactions began to throw an exception: "Cannot create asynchronous query while in a write transaction". But it was working fine before the migration.

```
let realm = try Realm()
let allMessages = realm.objects(Message.self)
let messages = allMessages.filter("(state == 1) AND (dateSent <= %@)",  dateSent)
try realm.write ({
   messages.forEach { message in message.state = .seen }
})
```

At the beginning of the transaction it throws an exception. Why this is happening and how could I fix it?

Comment: Please try moving the queries into the Transaction

Answer (score 2):

Was facing the same issue in my code, and it turned out that *beginning* the write transaction was triggering a collection notification that in turn created a new RLMResults and added a notification block to it, which means I was calling `addNotificationBlock` inside of a write transaction and crashing.

If you can reproduce, put a breakpoint in `results.cpp - void Results::prepare_async()` where the exception is thrown and see what your code is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are mutating `messages` in the `forEach`, this might be the cause of crash.

Try something like this:

```
let realm = try Realm()
let allMessages = realm.objects(Message.self)
let results = allMessages.filter("(state == 1) AND (dateSent <= %@)",  dateSent)
let messages = Array(results)
try realm.write ({
   messages.forEach { message in message.state = .seen }
})
```

Probably it's not the best solution, since you'll load all messages on memory, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to move the queries into the transaction.

```
let realm = try Realm()
try realm.write ({
     let allMessages = realm.objects(Message.self)
     let messages = allMessages.filter("(state == 1) AND (dateSent <= %@)",  dateSent)
     messages.forEach { message in message.state = .seen }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you are doing findAllAsync inside a change listener
https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5771#issuecomment-442004078

I've handled the queries with async/await and everything is good now.